# Emploi du mot propre "Bérézina"

Tags: usage, étymologie, histoire

Dans un blog de Le Monde, je rencontre :

> Au plan mondial, le résultat est à peine meilleur. Elle (la France) figure au 37e rang sur 70 pays classés. Une **Bérézina**.

Je sais que *Bérézina* est le lieu d'une grande bataille. Pourquoi l'auteur fait référence à cette bataille et pas à Waterloo ?
Est-ce parce que le journal a un registre plus soutenu et s'adresse à des personnes bien éduquées ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La *Bérézina* est passée dans le langage courant comme synonyme d'échec cuisant, d'humiliation. Il ne s'agit donc pas d'une coquetterie de cet auteur. On peut dire tout simplement *c'est la Bérézina*.

Bizarrement, la bataille de la Bérézina s'est pourtant conclue sur une victoire française ! Mais cette victoire fut acquise au prix de fortes pertes, et notamment grâce à une action de retrait particulièrement dure pour l'armée napoléonienne, qui dut abandonner une grosse partie de ses troupes sur une rive de la Bérézina, laissant les retardataires dans le froid et à la merci des troupes russes. La bataille de la Bérézina est donc rentrée dans l'imaginaire collectif des Français comme un épisode tragique et humiliant de la campagne de Russie, qui est elle-même souvent vue comme une campagne ratée, et en quelque sorte le début de la fin pour Napoléon.

*Waterloo* peut aussi être utilisé comme métaphore pour un échec cuisant, mais avec une nuance supplémentaire: un *Waterloo* est un échec définitif, qui met fin à quelque chose (une carrière, une suite de succès, etc), tout comme la bataille de Waterloo signa la fin du règne de Napoléon.

> La défaite de Jospin aux élections présidentielles fut son Waterloo: il quitta la vie politique définitivement.

Answer (score 1):

See the very classic graph of army losses in Napoleon's campaign in Russia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Joseph_Minard  Can you see the Berezina crossing on the left of the return, and what a minuscule proportion was left after that?  Maybe you superficially look like you won, but it's really a deep loss

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness I add [Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/c-est-la-berezina.php) lemma:

> **C'est la Bérézina**
>
> *C'est une défaite cuisante, une déroute complète.*
>
> *C'est une situation extrêmement désagréable.*
>
> **Origine**
>
> Nous sommes en
> 1812. Dans trois ans, on fêtera le tricentenaire de la bataille de Marignan. Mais cela n'effleure pas du tout l'esprit des quelques
> centaines de milliers d'hommes que Napoléon emmène envahir la Russie
> pour flanquer une pâtée mémorable à son armée.
>
> L'Empereur n'a toutefois pas prévu la politique de terre brûlée que
> les Russes vont appliquer (Moscou, en particulier, ville construite en
> bois sera la proie des flammes), empêchant ainsi les hommes et les
> animaux de se ravitailler suffisamment alors que le froid devient
> pénétrant. Avant que la troupe entière ne meure de faim, et sans
> réponse du tsar Alexandre Ier à ses offres de négociation, l'empereur
> décide la retraite. Les autres routes étant bloquées, elle se fait par
> le même chemin qu'à l'aller, via des terres déjà ravagées. Alors que
> les hommes ont faim et froid et sont harcelés par les Russes, à la fin
> du mois de novembre, ils arrivent devant la Bérézina, rivière de
> Biélorussie large d'une centaine de mètres et profonde de deux à trois
> mètres.
>
> L'eau étant glaciale, il n'est pas question de traverser à la nage.
> Travaillant dans des conditions insupportables, les pontonniers du
> général Éblé vont réaliser deux ponts alors que la température tombe à
> moins trente degrés et que l'eau charrie des gros blocs de glace. Des
> soixante-dix mille hommes qui sont face à la rivière, seuls quarante
> mille vont pouvoir la franchir, les ponts étant ensuite détruits pour
> empêcher l'ennemi de les emprunter, alors qu'ils reste de l'autre côté
> des quantités de soldats retardataires.
>
> C'est de cette déroute historique que vient notre expression, symbole
> d'échec complet ou de situation tragique insurmontable.
>
> Exemple « Une fois admis, on croit vraiment - mais vraiment ! - qu'à
> la sortie on aura le choix entre des dizaines d'offres d'emploi,
> provenant d'entreprises plus sympas les unes que les autres et qu'on
> pourra négocier un énorme salaire. Après tout, c'est justifié, on en a
> bavé pour arriver là, il est temps de récolter les fruits de son
> travail. Alors, quand on s'aperçoit que dehors, c'est la Bérézina,
> qu'il n'y a plus de boulot pour personne, même pas pour nous, on tombe
> de haut. » Gildas Vivier - Sexe, fric, glande & diplôme : les écoles
> de commerce dévoilées.

I also found that the very word is not easily interpreted in other languages

> [Bérézina](https://europeisnotdead.com/europe-is-not-deadfr/disco/mots-europeens/mots-intraduisibles-europeens/) – « C’est la bérézina ! » exprime bien plus qu’un échec
> grave, une défaite. L’origine du mot vient de la bataille de Bérézina
> en 1812 dans l’actuelle Biélorussie, entre l’armée française de
> Napoléon et l’armée russe de Koutousov, durant laquelle beaucoup de
> soldats français moururent en essayant de traverser la rivière gelée
> Berezina.